# How to get jenkins BUILD_NUMBER in webdriverio config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

My automation project is setup in Jenkins pipeline. I am using custom webdriverio service in wdio config file. I tried 
`const buildNum = process.env.BUILD_NUMBER;` but it returns `null`. Also I get this error[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my project:

In the wdio-conf file i have this variable declared above the `exports`

```
const buildUrl = process.env.BUILD_URL || '';
```

In the jenkins, i have the below while triggering the test:

```
BUILD_URL=${BUILD_URL} npm test
```

This passes in the URL when triggered from jenkins or assign `''` when not triggered from jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add build step in shell file first as below..

```
export BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Then call `process.env.BUILD_NUMBER`

For Windows bat file add below..

```
SET BUILD_NUMBER=%BUILD_NUMBER%
```

Then call `process.env.BUILD_NUMBER`